# Deserialize OneNote JSon result

Tags: json, onenote

I'm trying to deserialize some OneNote API results. Below is my:

1. Example result from notebook query
2. Sample Class
3. Code to deserialize  (two attempts obj1  and obj2

   ```
   Content-Type: application/json
   X-CorrelationId: <GUID>
   Status: 200 OK
   {
     "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#notebooks","value":[
       {
         "isDefault":false,
   "userRole":"Contributor",
   "isShared":true,
   "sectionsUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/notebook ID/sections",
   "sectionGroupsUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/notebook ID/sectionGroups",
   "links":{
           "oneNoteClientUrl":{
             "href":"https:{client URL}"
           },"oneNoteWebUrl":{
             "href":"https://{web URL}"
           }
         },
   "id":"notebook ID",
   "name":"notebook name",
   "self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/notebook ID",
   "createdBy":"user name",
   "lastModifiedBy":"user name",
   "createdTime":"2013-10-05T10:57:00.683Z",
   "lastModifiedTime":"2014-01-28T18:49:00.47Z"
       },{
         "isDefault":true,
   "userRole":"Owner",
   "isShared":false,
   "sectionsUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/notebook ID/sections",
   "sectionGroupsUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/notebook ID/sectionGroups",
   "links":{
           "oneNoteClientUrl":{
             "href":"https://{client URL}"
           },"oneNoteWebUrl":{
             "href":"https://{web URL}"
           }
         },
   "id":"notebook ID",
   "name":"notebook name",
   "self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/notebook ID",
   "createdBy":"user name",
   "lastModifiedBy":"user name",
   "createdTime":"2011-07-20T03:54:46.283Z",
   "lastModifiedTime":"2014-06-24T20:49:42.227Z"
       }
     ]
   }


    [DataContract]
       public class Notebooks
       {
           [DataMember]
           public bool isDefault { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string userRole { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string isShared { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string sectionsUrl { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string sectionGroupsUrl { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string oneNoteWebUrl { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string name { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string self { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string createdBy { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string lastModifiedBy { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string lastModifiedTime { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string id { get; set; }
           [DataMember]
           public string createdTime { get; set; }
       }
   ```

   // This sample web string returned from the Web Request is stored in this textbox
   string resultStr = resultTextBox.Text.ToString();

   ```
            var obj1 = DeserializeJSon<List<Notebooks>>(resultStr);

           foreach (Notebooks nb in obj1)
           {
              string id = nb.ToString();
           }

           DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Notebooks>));
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultStr));

          var obj2 = (List<Notebooks>)ser.ReadObject(stream);

           foreach (Notebooks nb in obj2)
           {
               string id = nb.id.ToString();
           }


       public static T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
       {
           DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
           T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
           return obj;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not being able to deserialize the result because the JSON returned by the OneNote API is not a List of Notebook objects. It is one main object with two properties: "@odata.context" and "value". "value" itself is a list of Notebook objects.

I suggest you make a class like the following

```
public class OneNoteJsonResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@odata.context")]
    public string ODataContext {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public List<Notebook> value {get; set;}
}
```

Then try deserializing the response using DataContractSerializer following this example:
[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

I personally would recommend using JSON.NET instead of the DataContractSerializer, as it provides more flexibility and better performance. You can install it easily using nuget.
http://james.newtonking.com/json

Let us know if you have any issues, happy coding!

EDIT: Also, the Notebook object you have is missing the "links" object, which would be another class of its own. (containing the oneNoteClientUrl and OneNoteWebUrl)

Answer (score 1):

response string cannot be used verbatim with your data model. start from "value".

alternatively, have a look at http://json2csharp.com/

hth